# Laravel Elixir minify js file without combine them

Tags: laravel

for example I have a common.js , and regagent.js, how can I minify them without combine them these two, because mix.copy and mix.scripts seems can't do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use separate `scripts()` methods for every file:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts([
        'resources/assets/js/admin.js',
    ], 'public/js/admin.js', './');
    mix.scripts([
        'resources/assets/js/main.js',
    ], 'public/js/main.js', './');
}
```

Then run [`gulp --production`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#running-elixir) command to minify each file.

Comment: But If I have 10+ files then I have to do that as well ?

Comment: @YiuKitman gulpfule.js is JS, so minify files inside a JS loop.